# Django Admin verification

Tags: python, django

Please, I am currently working on a project for a modeling agency where the admin verifies the details of a new model after completing a registration form.
The project is using python django framework.

This is the breakdown;

- A new model fills a form.
- The form is send to the administrator's email for notification and confirmation of the data before being added to the database .
- The new model is then added to the database .

I have little understanding about the above problem, I will be very grateful for any kind of help in this, thanks

Comment: So are you asking how you can add the model information to the database only _after_ the admin has reviewed it?

Comment: Exactly ... @DanielHolmes

Comment: Why do you not want to have the model information added to the DB initially? The admin can just delete if they don't want it confirmed.

Comment: Could there be a Boolean field to verify the model if it added to the database directly ? and i want the admin to received a notification through email after a new model fills the form. @DanielHolmes

Comment: It is still unclear how you intend on having the admin verify the model information. I assume they would need to login to your system and verify the details there?

Comment: I see the answer is no longer accepted. Would you mind posting your alternative solution if you have found it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would I would do (which I think is the simplest solution based on the information you have given) is to have an additional field that would tell you if the information has been verified by the admin. I would also not call the database table `Model`, because it may cause some confusion with what Django terms a `model`.

```
class Registration(models.Model)
    # all the registration form fields
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So once the admin is satisfied with the information, they can login to your site and set`verified=True`.

As for the email notification, use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/) as a staring point. You will need to figure out the details of how this is to be accomplished based on your applications. Or you should ask a separate question with a bit more information on exactly what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: @Bjboss007 you're welcome. If this answered your question, please consider marking it as accepted.